# Python Selenium Multithread Add Values From Each Thread Together

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, python-multithreading

First of all idk if this is a duplicate question. I'm sorry if it is. But here is my problem.
I'm multi-threading and I want to add 2 values from each thread together. Here is my code for reference

```
def clicks():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(#url)
    place = #element of the place i want to click
    count = 0
    while True:
        place.click()
        count+=1
        print(f'Clicks: {count}')
        #for every click count + 1 and then prints the number of count
```

The above code works perfectly for single thread. But when I multithread it, this is the output :

```
Clicks: 50
Clicks: 102
```

I want to add the count from each thread together, I can't figure out a solution to do that. Would appreciate for any help, Thanks in advance.
Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/Nm2dC74B

Comment: please provide some more code

Comment: @farhanjatt alright I edited the pastebin link there for the full code.

Comment: link is not working

Comment: try this one https://pastebin.com/BCBZSnZS